# JURI::getInstance() query missing

Tags: php, joomla, uri

I want to have a little login link on a Joomla page. If I click on this link and login, it should return me to the page I was before. For that I need the query of the current page like `option=com_component&article=....` But If I use `JURI::getInstance()` the query is empty (false).

This is the code:

```
<?php
$user = & JFactory::getUser();
$site = & JURI::getInstance()->getQuery();
$return = urlencode(base64_encode('index.php?'.$site));
?>
<a class="<?php echo $user->id? 'logout-a' : 'login-a';?>" href="index.php?option=com_users&amp;view=login&amp;return=<?php echo $return ?>">
<?php
    if ($user->id) echo 'Logout';
    else echo 'Login';
?>
</a>
```

The return works, but it only returns me to `index.php`, not to `index.php?option=...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JFactory::getURI()`.This may help you

```
<?php
$user = & JFactory::getUser();
$site = & JFactory::getURI();
$return = $uri->toString();
?>
<a class="<?php echo $user->id? 'logout-a' : 'login-a';?>" href="index.php?option=com_users&amp;view=login&amp;return=<?php echo $return ?>">
<?php
    if ($user->id) echo 'Logout';
    else echo 'Login';
?>
</a>
```

Comment: No, it's the same problem, the site only contains 'http://.../index.php' without the query part.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it doesn't work too. The same problem.

Comment: @TIIUNDER what version of joomla are you using?

Comment: It's Joomla 2.5.7 and I use this little script in a module "Flexi Custom Code"

Comment: @TIIUNDER I have add another method to get the current url ,you can try this if `JURI::current` doesn't work

Comment: Same problem, there must be something which blocks the access to the parameters :-(

Comment: Thank you, this was the hint. I disabled the cache of the module, now it works. BTW, I'm using my code from the beginning, because it muste be only the query and encoded in base64.

Comment: @TIIUNDER good to know that finally something works for you :)